# Invalid form elements appear without trying to submit the form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bootstrap-4

I have an html registration page where a user inputs information and then submits the form and the info is entered in a database. If a user tries to submit the form without entering all the information required, I have an invalid-feedback class that catches it before it submits and tells the user which info they need to input before submission.

> The form works perfectly when running locally on my computer but when I upload it to an actual server, the registration page just shows all the invalid-feedback messages without even the user submitting the form.

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with this or would know if this is a bootstrap problem where I'm missing a file?
I'm just looking for suggestions of what could be wrong. I use bootstrap, nodejs, css, html, express, js..

(Correct) This is what it looks like on localhost:

[image: This is what it looks like on localhost]

(Incorrect) This is what it looks like on my server:

[image: This is what it looks like on my server]

Comment: Hmmm... the background-color styling is different as well... I wonder if perhaps you are missing a CSS file or a JS file in your Production environment?

Comment: Do have a minified version of your local code on the server?

Comment: Please share the code, otherwise we can not help.

Comment: Don't edit the question to include the answer, please add a new answer below.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap 4 then you need to add was-validated class which would be added dynamically after validating the form via client-side JavaScript. something like this:

```
<form class="container was-validated" novalidate="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Input with success</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i1" id="inputSuccess1">
        <div class="valid-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Input with danger</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="i2" required="" id="inputSuccess2">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">That didn't work.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Text</button>
    </div>
</form>
```